# Cause ctrl+z is undo in Intelij , how to finish the InputStream in it?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, undo

I'm a greenhand in Java, and when I learnt the IOstream in Intelij, the textbook told me to type Ctrl+Z to finish the InputStream. But I found it didn't work.Then I remembered that Ctrl+Z is undo in Intelij,so how to finish the InputStream in Intelij?

Comment: If you're focusing the terminal, it should work (if I remember correctly).

Comment: You could try Ctrl+W. I had problems with mix-ups between those keys. Just to be sure, you're not typing "Cirl+Z"? You are using the Ctrl+Z combo (i.e. control key plus Z key)?

Comment: you can go under `File->Settings->Keymap` then choose the most right magnifier (+3 rechtangles) and then in the input press your combo. Then it apears what your combo is doing in this editor. You can also change it after this.

Comment: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-68972

Answer (score 0):

1. `File->Settings->Keymap`
2. search`Send EOF`
3. `Add Keyboard Shortcut`